# chicken scheme installation gets stuck during "make install"

Tags: macos, scheme, chicken-scheme

I am trying to install chicken using brew

```
Salils-MacBook-Pro:bin salilwadnerkar$ brew install chicken
==> Downloading http://code.call-cc.org/releases/4.7.0/chicken-4.7.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/chicken-4.7.0.tar.gz
==> make PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.7.0 PLATFORM=macosx C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang ARCH=x86-64
==> make install PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.7.0 PLATFORM=macosx C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang ARCH=x86-64
```

But, it gets stuck at this phase. I also tried to use csi as it appeared to have been already installed. But I don't get the command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in:

This [github issue](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8191), instead of clang, which is a default compiler on Mac OSX, we need to use gcc to build chicken.

```
brew install -vd chicken --use-gcc
```

(Ignore -vd, which I used for debugging this brew install)